# Выведите все элементы списка с четными индексами (то есть A[0], A[2], A[4], ...)

Tags: python

```
K = [1, 2, 6, 77, 18, 24, 45, 67, 111, 134, 667, 345]

for el in range(0,len(K)):
    if el % 2 == 0:
        print(el)
    else:
        continue
```

как вывести именно числа с четными индексами?

Comment: Используйте срезы: `K[::2]`

Comment: Какую именно ошибку выдает?

Comment: в Python не существует операторов/команд `For`, `If`, `Print`, `Else`, `Continue` - все они пишутся с маленькой буквы...

Comment: *как вывести именно числа с четными индексами?* - `print(K[el])` вместо `print(el)`. Дополнительно: пожалуйста, пишите **все** Ваши вопросы сразу. Менять вопрос по мере получения ответов не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как вывести именно числа с четными индексами?

```
K = [1, 2, 6, 77, 18, 24, 45, 67, 111, 134, 667, 345]

for el in range(0,len(K)):
    if el % 2 == 0:
        print(K[el])
    else:
        continue
```

Результат:

```
1
6
18
45
111
667
```

[Тест](https://repl.it/repls/KindlyMeagerRepositories)